# Does BinaryWriter(Stream stream) dispose the stream on BinaryWriter.Dispose()?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

In documentation for StreamWriter (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wtbhzte9(v=vs.110).aspx) it says "The StreamWriter object calls Dispose() on the provided Stream object when StreamWriter.Dispose is called."

Is same true for BinaryWriter(Stream stream), I don't see same note in here (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/atxb4f07(v=vs.110).aspx)?

I couldn't find anything either way in documentation, and the classes seem very related - one is for text files, the other for binary files, I expected same behavior in both and same note in both or neither.

Comment: In general, readers or writers wrapping a stream will close the stream when the reader/writer itself is closed. But there usually will be an overload that will allow you to control that.

Answer (score 1):

It does. If you don't want this behavior, there is an overload available that does not dispose the stream:

```
BinaryWriter(Stream output, Encoding encoding, bool leaveOpen)
```